# Apache Ignite - Thread gets blocked forever

Tags: gridgain, ignite

We have a cluster of 2 nodes A & B.

If we block the execution of a thread on Node A (I did it by remotely connecting to my VM and put a breakpoint), then node B thinks that node A is segmented(which is expected behavior).

After performing above scenario, any cache lookup on Node A get stuck and we never gets the result back from IgniteCache.

I have put together a test application to reproduce this issue. It's little tricky to reproduce this problem but I have tried best to provide instruction in README.md

If you are still not clear on how to reproduce it then I can provide a Video recording.

https://github.com/manish-panwar/ignite-thread-block-issue

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you set `IgniteConfiguration.setSegmentationPolicy` to `NOOP`. This means that nothing happens when the node is segmented and actually this policy assumes that you will create a listener for `EVT_NODE_SEGMENTED` event and provide your own handling. If you don't do this, it's better to set it to `STOP` (default value) so that the node is stopped immediately after segmentation. This will release all the threads.

Comment: I have already implemented a listener for EVT_NODE_SEGMENTED events. Please take a look at ProblemProducer

Comment: In this class I have added listener for EVT_NODE_SEGMENTED  https://github.com/manish-panwar/ignite-thread-block-issue/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/problem/ProblemProducer.java

Comment: There is only cache event listener. I don't see any listeners for `EVT_NODE_SEGMENTED`.

Comment: I defined CACHE_EVENTS in https://github.com/manish-panwar/ignite-thread-block-issue/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/problem/IgniteCacheConfig.java and implemented listener in https://github.com/manish-panwar/ignite-thread-block-issue/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/problem/IgniteCacheEventsListener.java. Let me know if you see something wrong in my implementation.

Comment: I see. But you just log the event, there are no actions preventing the segmented node from being stuck. Actually, custom logic here is needed only for very rare specific use cases. In most cases the best way is to just use `STOP` policy so that the node is stopped immediately after segmentation.

Comment: We don't want to STOP when segmentation occurs. We plan to add some logic in EVT_NODE_SEGMENTED listener. My real question is, when segmentation happens, why the cache lookup on segmented node get stuck forever?

Comment: Because some futures are not completed. What logic do you want to add there? In any case, this node is not functional anymore and you will end up stopping it anyway.

Comment: Our segmented node should continue serving the traffic (business reasons). We do will do cache warnup again on segmented node. Having said that, segmented node shouldn't block the thread on cache read.

Comment: If you stop or restart the node the reading thread will not be blocked. You will most likely get an exception and can retry the operation.